# Propriedade left não funciona em position fixed

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer com que uma div fique fixa no rodapé da página, no canto direito, mas não encostado no fim da página, deste modo usei, como de costume:

```
width:50px;
height:100px;
background:#fff;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:10;
```

Mas a div não recebeu a propriedade. Fui em inspecionar elemento no browser e sob o "left:10;" está um aviso "Invalid property value".
Alguém sabe me dizer algo sobre isso?

Comment: Você tem que indicar a unidade `px` ou `pt` etc.

Comment: Por que funciona com o "bottom:0;" sem a unidade, e não funciona com o left e com o right?

Comment: Pode ser uma limitação do browser.

Answer (score 1):

No canto direito, não encostado.

```
width:50px;
height:100px;
background:#fff;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:10px;
```

Comment: Neste caso eu vou usar position:fixed, tem alguma diferença?

Comment: O elemento apenas vai ficar fixo na tela em relação a tela do computador com `position: fixed`. Com `position: absolute` o elemento fica com a posição referente ao primeiro elemento pai com `position: relative` ou o elemento `html`.

Answer (score 0):

Funciona desde que o elemento pai esteja com `position: relative;`